# How to access the Visual interface for October?

Tags: php, wamp, octobercms

I installed October : https://octobercms.com/ on my wamp server and not sure how to access the visual interface I see in tutorials. Could anyone point me in the right direction on documentation on how to access it or let me know how to get to the visual interface?

Comment: It looks as though it is just using Laravel on the backend, why not check out the routes.php config file. This should answer all your questions.

Comment: Could you add an image or link pointing to the "Visual interface" you're talking about? Hard to help you with visual stuff without seeing.

Comment: Did you mean backend (control panel)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OctoberCMS backend interace is available (by default) in the `/backend` route.

Access: `yourapp.localhost/backend`.

In the installation process and after installed you can custom this updating the `config/cms.php` file.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Back-end URI prefix
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Specifies the URI prefix used for accessing back-end pages.
|
*/

'backendUri' => '/backend',
```